# CAML batch query - valid XML?

Tags: list, caml-query, xml, batch

The standard format of a CAML batch query is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:Batch OnError="Continue">
  <Method ID="">
    <SetList>288a3dfc-ec52-45aa-a370-4ab01e3d0a05</SetList>
    <SetVar Cmd="Save" />
    <SetVar ID="New" />
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Foo">bar</SetVar>
  </Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

The problem with this is it isn't valid XML and thus can't be created with the `System.Xml.Linq` classes. The "ows" namespace is never declared before it is used.

Does anyone know if its possible/legal to actually declare the OWS namespace, and if so, to what? (Notice the ??? below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:Batch OnError="Continue" xmlns:ows="???">
  <Method ID="">
    <SetList>288a3dfc-ec52-45aa-a370-4ab01e3d0a05</SetList>
    <SetVar Cmd="Save" />
    <SetVar ID="New" />
    <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Dog">5</SetVar>
  </Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ows namespace, Batch works just fine without it when I've called batch updates via web services.

Comment: From what I've read the web services CAML queries are different from the CAML you use for the SharePoint Object Model (which is what this is for).